# Laravel5: Form-model binding - Radio buttons auto select causing problems when creating new record

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Form-Model binding and the same view partial for both creating and editing a user.

While trying auto-select radio buttons based on db values upon `Edit`,
The correct item selects by default, which is the expected result. But when I try creating a new user using the same form partial, it gives an error `Undefined variable: user` because we didn't pass a `$user` variable on the create method, which seems unnecessary. How do I fix this?

**Controller Methods:**

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('backend/users/create');
    }
public function edit(User $user)
    return view('backend/users/edit', compact('user'));
}
```

**Form radio buttons:**

```
{{ Form::radio('level', 1, $user, []) }}
{{ Form::radio('level', 2, $user, []) }}
{{ Form::radio('level', 3, $user, []) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't have `$user` var in create method so try like this:

```
{!! Form::radio('level', 1, isset($user) ? $user : null, []) !!}
{!! Form::radio('level', 2, isset($user) ? $user : null, []) !!}
{!! Form::radio('level', 3, isset($user) ? $user : null, []) !!}
```

I've also put `Form::radio` in `{!! !!}` because in L5 `{{ }}` will escape all the html tags with `htmlentities`.

But this is still not good way. If you're passing the model I suppose that you want to bind all form with model's data, so you should bind `$user` on the form like this:

```
@if(isset($user))
    {!! Form::model($user, [...]) !!}
@else
    {!! Form::open([...]) !!}
@endif
```